# writing a huge file and Java heap space

Tags: java, file, exception, client-server

I am trying to write a huge file, between **500mb to 1.5 gb**, into the disk. 
i used `zipOutputStream` to zip it then send it over the network

but in client, when im trying to unzip and
write it, it gives me `Java heap space.` exception

```
  try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
                int fileLength = (int)zipEntry.getSize();

                byte[] fileByte = new byte[fileLength];
                zips.read(fileByte);
                fos.write(fileByte);
            }
```

i know thats quite big memory allocation for an array of bytes, but how possibly i can fix it?

Comment: You can read/write portions of the file at a time.  This is how Stream are designed to be used.  How about you read/write 8K at a time?

Comment: @PeterLawrey how to assign the size to the stream?

Comment: You could also accomplish the same thing with `Files.copy(zips, outFile.toPath());`.  See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Comment: @VGR care to make it like an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `byte[]` array you are making is your buffer, the buffer serves as the temporary location in the heap while in transit from your `InputStream` to your `OutputStream`. Unless you want your program to use 500mb - 1.5gb in memory you need to reduce your buffer size. Here is a common method I use for doing this operation. This method uses a 1kb buffer, you can play with the size and see what suits you best.

```
/**
 * writes all bytes from inputStream to outputStream
 * @param source
 * @param destination
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void pipeStreams(java.io.InputStream source, java.io.OutputStream destination) throws IOException {

    // 1kb buffer
    byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    while((read=source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        destination.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    destination.flush();
}
```

Your code using this method would look something like

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
    pipeStreams(zips, fos);
}
```

Comment: that worked wekk, nearly 2 min to transfer the file, i was stuck in the part that how to make it to read only several KB , and here you showed me. thanks

Comment: however, i wonder if the buffer size, for example 10KB, does it means the spead is 10X or not?

Comment: oh my typo, i meant speed

Comment: i know the answer is no, but , in this case, what about we define a buffer which uses the max possibility space for buffering, instead of small 1KB buffer?

Comment: @lonesome Java programs have memory limits, by creating a byte[] array of size say 200mb will tell Java to create and hold a memory slot of size 200mb for some data to be placed in. Now while there is no data actually in that 200mb it still is required to allocate the space for it. It is generally better to define a buffer of size that is applicable for your program. Heres a fun little test. Put a `println(read)` in the while loop of the `pipeStream` method. It will tell you how many bytes were read into the array, then increase your array size to like 1mb and see how much is actually used.

Comment: so you mean, it doesnt necessarily uses the whole buffer, although the file is bigger than buffer size?

Comment: @lonesome no... err yes, you are correct, especially when reading and writing over a network.

Comment: @lonesome Most likely the bottle neck is your download speed.  Only if you seeing high CPU utilisation (ignoring system time) does it suggest a larger buffer might help btw there is no harm in trying this yourself.  Try 4 KB, 16 KB, 64 KB etc and see if you think it makes a difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i didnt say it made huge differences, i just asked that question on purpose to raise the next question . in fact, if in same conditions, it was almost the same duration for any of the buffer size

Comment: @lonesome not sure what the next question was but you can have a file which is smaller or larger than the buffer size.  Note: the socket already has a buffer of around 64 KB.  Each TCP packet is typically around 1.5 KB so if you read fast enough you will only ever see 1.5 KB at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the entire file into memory all at once, you can accomplish the same thing with `Files.copy(zips, outFile.toPath());`.  Documentation for the Files.copy method is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Comment: so, whiich way do u think is better? buffering or this copy method?

Comment: `Files.copy` is better, because using it is more readable, and I believe it currently does its own buffering, so it certainly can't be worse than doing it oneself.

Comment: I'm still running out of heap space using Files.copy... is there a way to specify buffersize using this?

Comment: @Rimer I would need to see your code.  It should not be possible to run out of space unless you tried to read the entire file into a ByteArrayOutputStream or something.  I know I have copied 3 GB files using Files.copy without any issue.

Comment: My mistake i was running the wrong code branch when I  was running out of heap space. Files.copy did the trick! It uses an 8KB buffer btw i found out from source snooping...